# Razor pages - dates values don't transfer to another page

Tags: c#, razor-pages

I'm learning C# for only 3 months now so still a beginner that has lot to learn. I'm currently following a tutorial of Tim Corey but I've run into some problems I can't fix. I did the exact same thing as shown in the tutorial but my result isn't like in the course.

We are building a hotel app. Users get to see a webpage made with asp.net razorpages, where they give in a startdate and enddate and then get to see a list of available roomtypes for that period of time. This part works like it should. At each available roomtype there is a link which direct to a new page, the 'BookRoom' page. By clicking the 'Book now' link the values of the roomtypeId, startdate and enddate need to be passed trough from the RoomSearch page to the BookRoom page and this is where I'm having a problem.

The roomId is passing trough fine but the startdate and enddate are always ending up as 01/01/0001 when transfered to the BookRoom page. When I hover over the 'book now' link I can see that the roomId and the correct Start and EndDate are in the URL. When I click the link and go to the BookRoom page, the URL on the BookRoom page look likes this 'https://localhost:7139/BookRoom?roomtypeid=3&startdate=19%2F04%2F2023&enddate=20%2F04%2F2023 ' so it seems the dates are being transferred yet in Visual Studio both values of startdate and enddate keep saying 01/01/0001 as values. So I'm really confused why it isn't working correctly. Anyone seeing what is causing this?

This is how the pages look like:

```
@page
@model HotelApp.Web.Pages.RoomSearchModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Room Search";
}

<h1>Room Search</h1>

<form method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="@Model.StartDate"></label>
        <input asp-for="@Model.StartDate"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="@Model.EndDate"></label>
    <input asp-for="@Model.EndDate"/>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
</form>

@if (Model.AvailableRoomTypes?.Count > 0)
{
    <br>
    <h2>Results</h2>
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Room Type</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var room in Model.AvailableRoomTypes)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <strong>@room.Title</strong><br>
                        @room.Description
                    </td>
                    <td>@string.Format("{0:C}", room.Price)</td>
                    <td><a asp-page="/BookRoom" asp-route-roomtypeid="@room.Id" 
                        asp-route-startdate="@Model.StartDate.ToShortDateString()" 
                        asp-route-enddate="@Model.EndDate.ToShortDateString()">
                        Book Now</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table> 

    
}
```

And the bookroom page:

```
namespace HotelApp.Web.Pages
{
    public class BookRoomModel : PageModel
    {
        [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
        public int RoomTypeId { get; set; }


        [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }


        [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
        public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }


        [BindProperty]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [BindProperty]
        public string LastName { get; set; }


        public void OnGet()
        {
        }
        public IActionResult OnPost()
        {
            return RedirectToPage("/Index");
        }
    }
}
```

I triple checked the page on type errors since I'm following the tutorial step by step. I looked up some extra info about razorpages outside what I've learned from the course but couldn't find out what's wrong. Perhaps someone more experienced knows what's wrong.

Comment: Did you checked the format of date in which you are getting the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the dates in `yyyy-MM-dd` format so that any localisation issues are mitigated:

```
<td>
    <a asp-page="/BookRoom" asp-route-roomtypeid="@room.Id" 
       asp-route-startdate="@Model.StartDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")" 
       asp-route-enddate="@Model.EndDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")">Book Now</a>
</td>
```